Finding rows in a data.frame that are the same on one variable but different on another variable in R
In my DATA below, how could I filter the rows where the Nm values are the same but Descr values are different to achieve my Desired_out below?
DATA <- read.table(header=T, text ="
Cd    Nm     Descr
710   spa    Castilian
4260  spa    Spanish
2290  gr     Greek
1213  gr    Greek_b
1765  ger    German
2340  ita    Italian
")

Desired_output <- read.table(header=T, text ="
Cd    Nm     Descr
710   spa    Castilian
4260  spa    Spanish
2290  gr     Greek
1213  gr    Greek_b")



With dplyr, detecting duplicated entries with vec_duplicate_detect from vctrs
library(dplyr)

DATA %>% 
  filter(all(!vctrs::vec_duplicate_detect(Descr)) & n() > 1, .by = Nm)
    Cd  Nm     Descr
1  710 spa Castilian
2 4260 spa   Spanish
3 2290  gr     Greek
4 1213  gr   Greek_b


library(dplyr)

DATA |>
  filter(n_distinct(Descr) > 1, .by = Nm)
#     Cd  Nm     Descr
# 1  710 spa Castilian
# 2 4260 spa   Spanish
# 3 2290  gr     Greek
# 4 1213  gr   Greek_b


This seems more direct to me.

The filter should be filter(n_distinct(Descr) == n() & n() > 1, .by = Nm) to work for all cases. With just n_distinct(Descr) > 1 could still contain duplicates within the group.

@AndreWildberg What other cases are you referring to?

E.g. rbind(DATA[1,], list(324, "spa", "Spanish"), DATA[2:6,])

If that is the case in their data then they can do as you proposed or all(!duplicated(Descr)), n_distinct(Descr) > 1

Here is base R trick with ave + var
subset(DATA, ave(as.integer(factor(Descr)), Nm, FUN = var) > 0)

which gives
  Cd   Nm  Descr    
1  710 spa Castilian
2 4260 spa Spanish  
3 2290 gr  Greek    
4 1213 gr  Greek_b  

